# R code error: Please provide variables names in impulse that are in the set of endogenous variables

Tags: r, time-series, var, modeling

I am trying to generate impulse response function for my VECM ,but the system is throwing an error that says

> Please provide variables names in impulse that are in the set of endogenous variables.

How can I understand the root cause of the issue?

The sample code is as follows:

```
model1 = VECM(data.frame(macv$ABN, macv$DAN, macv$CRL), lag=10, estim ="ML")
summary(model1)

library(vars)
irf(model1,impulse = "ABN", response = "DAN", boot=FALSE, n.ahead = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `colnames` of the `data.frame` that you generate in the first row are `macv.ABN`, `macv.DAN`and `macv.CRL`. Therefore there are no variables `ABN` and `DAN` in `model1`. Thus the working code should be:

```
library(vars)
model1 = VECM(data.frame(ABN=macv$ABN, DAN=macv$DAN,CRL=macv$CRL), lag=10, estim ="ML")
summary(model1)


irf(model1,impulse = "ABN", response = "DAN", boot=FALSE, n.ahead = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Grada  for your help ,that makes sense :)